# Brute force roots of a univariate polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I am given a polynomial, where (a, b, c) are integers (positive and negative).

$$
    ax^2+bx+c
$$

I need to create a simple brute force method to find the roots of this univariate polynomial.

Is there a trivial method to determine the closed form boundaries of possible x-values for the root of this polynomial?

Comment: $$\left[\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right] ∪ \left[\dfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},\dfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right]$$?

Comment: I know there are lots of ways to derive the roots of this polynomial. Perhaps my question should really ask whether or not there is a simple way I can put a rough boundary on possible roots based on the input of a, b and c?

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are not bounded, there is no way to bound the possible roots...

Comment: What if we determine the bounds based on the input. Let's say a=10, b=(-100), c=0. Am I able to absolutely say that the root of this polynomial will be no larger or smaller then some arbitrary number?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What arbitrary number would I compare it to? That's what I'm trying to determine.

Comment: This is a vast subject, but the Cauchy bound on the roots of the polynomials will work if they're integers.  In general, there are many root isolation algorithms out there (Sturm, Descartes, Continued Fractions, Bolzano)

Comment: @MichaelBurr the only reason I'm looking for a very trivial method is because this logic will need to be done using a Turing machine. I'm trying to keep it very simple, for my own sake.

Comment: The [Cauchy Bound](http://captainblack.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/cauchys-upper-bound-for-the-roots-of-a-polynomial/) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @MichaelBurr perfect! This is exactly what I hoped for.

Comment: @Trent The Cauchy Bound is great and all, but it basically finds the max value for the absolute value of the roots (which is basically the largest absolute value of the roots), which doesn't provide too much insight... or is it just me?

Answer (score 0):

### Cauchy's Bound

Suppose 
$$
f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n−1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0
$$ 
is a
polynomial of degree n with n ≥ 1. Let M be the largest of the numbers: $$\frac{|a_0|}{|a_n|} , \frac{|a_1|}{|a_n|} , . . . , \frac{|a_{n−1}|}{|a_n|}$$
Then all the real zeros of f lie in in the interval $$[−(M + 1), M + 1]$$

Comment: Uh, well, that's quite an astounding statement... how do you propose we narrow it down further, with the context that this happens to be quadratic polynomial...?

Answer (score 0):

The max/min of the quadratic occurs at $x=-\frac b{2a}$, and the $y$ value of the point is given as $y=\frac{b^2}{2a}+c$ (I refer to this when I say $y$.)

If $y<0$ and $a<0$ or $y>0$ and $a>0$, all roots are complex.

If $y<0$ and $a>0$ or $y>0$ and $a<0$, all roots are real.

$|r_1+\frac b{2a}|=|r_2+\frac b{2a}|$

**- - Regardless of if the roots are real or not - -**

If $|y|<|a|$, then the roots $r_1,r_2$ are bounded: $|\frac1a\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}-c-\frac b2\right)|<|r+\frac b{2a}|<1$

If $|y|>|a|$, then the roots are bounded $1<|r+\frac b{2a}|<|\frac1a\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}-c-\frac b2\right)|$

If $|y|=|a|$, then we can conclude $|r+\frac b{2a}|=1$

**- - Explanation - -**

So I sat down and considered the impact each of the three constants, $a,b,c$, had on the quadratic.  I determined that $b,c$ do not contribute to the shape of the graph, but only to the critical point of the graph.  Similarly, $a$ only contributes to the magnitude of the function.  The trick is that the overall shape remains the same, and I determined points that were of importance, and set bounds from there.  I note that you can improve the bound, but it would eventually lead to the quadratic formula...